# Excluir os links do retorno da função wp_list_categories();

Tags: wordpress

Estou tentando retornar só a lista de `taxomanias` de um `custom post type` chamado "Portfolio". Só preciso dos nomes das categorias.

O código abaixo está retornando as categorias com links, alguém sabe como excluir esses links?

```
$taxonomy_names = get_object_taxonomies('portfolio');

if(count($taxonomy_names) > 0)
{
     foreach($taxonomy_names as $tax)
     {
         $args = array(
              'orderby' => 'name',
              'hide_empty' => 0,
              'show_count' => 0,
              'pad_counts' => 0,
              'hierarchical' => 1,
              'taxonomy' => $tax,
              'title_li' => ''
            );

        wp_list_categories($args);

     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Segundo a documentação do `wp_list_categories` no codex do Wordpress, não há um argumento para omitir os links na lista.

Você pode iterar manualmente usando a função `get_terms`:

```
$taxonomy_names = get_object_taxonomies('portfolio');

if(count($taxonomy_names) > 0) {
    foreach($taxonomy_names as $tax) {
        $terms = get_terms($tax);

        foreach ( $terms as $term ){

            $output  = "";
            $output .= "<li>";
            $output .= $term->name;
            $output .= "</li>";

            echo $output;

        }
    }
}
```

Isso deve retornar o resultado que você deseja.